# C# Mail Kit - Office 365 - Server issue

Tags: c#, email, office365, mailkit

I have been using Mailkit in my C# webapps for a while now. Never had any issues before, but today I started getting the following error when I attempt to send:

> AuthenticationException: ErrorInProcessing: 4.7.0 Temporary server error. Please try again later. PRX4 [SYXPR01CA0117.ausprd01.prod.outlook.com]
>   Authenticate

I was originally running MailKit 1.6 but as this has happened I have upgraded Mailkit to 2.4 in an attempt to fix this.

Below is the code I am using to send emails.

```
        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.LocalDomain = "smtp.office365.com";
            await client.ConnectAsync("smtp.office365.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls).ConfigureAwait(false);
            client.Authenticate("EmailAddress", "Password");
            await client.SendAsync(emailMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await client.DisconnectAsync(true).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

If anyone has come across this issue or has some ideas to get around this, let me know!

Called Microsoft to confirm they didn't believe they were having issues with there exchange servers at the moment.

UPDATE

After more testing have confirmed I can telnet to the instance of office365 fine. and I can also send an email using Powershell with the following code

```
$msolcred = get-credential
Send-MailMessage –From emailaddress –To emailaddress  –Subject “Test Email” –Body “Test” -SmtpServer smtp.office365.com -Credential $msolcred -UseSsl -Port 587
```

Answer (score 0):

That error message comes from your SMTP server and not MailKit. The error seems to indicate that it is indeed a *temporary* server problem.

Also of note: there is no such thing as MailKit 2.4. The latest version is 1.16.1.

Comment: Hey jstedfast - Thanks for the reply, your right my NuGet was bonking out on me, a few refreshed and the avil version is back down to 1.16.1 - I was hoping it was a mailkit issue without much evidence as with Office 365 I can affect the exchange servers where I could have fixed a mailkit issue! I maybe someone else has had this happen or else I need to hope MS get their side fixed.

Comment: Just confirmed Mailkit was the issue. Rolled it out and replaced it with the .net mail STMPClient and everything is working again.

Comment: Then please submit a bug report and include a protocol log so it can be debugged.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to the next line:

```
client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
```

so your code could be:

```
    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        client.LocalDomain = "smtp.office365.com";
        await client.ConnectAsync("smtp.office365.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls).ConfigureAwait(false);
        client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
        client.Authenticate("EmailAddress", "Password");
        await client.SendAsync(emailMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await client.DisconnectAsync(true).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I rolled Mailkit out and replaced it with the standard .net SMTP and that resolved my issue. I quite liked the async calls in MailKit but it wasn't worth stuffing around.